# Print multiple copies of pdf with individual text on each copy

Tags: pdf, printing

Im looking for a way to print a 1 page PDF document multiple times and stamping a individual text(for example a name) on the bottom of each page. Ex
Copy1 Arthur
Copy2 Charles
Copy3 Steve

Something like gsprint.exe -Copies 3 -Stamps "Arthur,Charles,Steve" testpdf.pdf

I have tried the approach of creating a document with multiple identical copies and then stamping the text with "cpdf", that creates a small file but it takes way to long to print regardless of spooling or direct print.

Comment: Which operating system, and what product used for printing?

Comment: It'a a windows system, but if linux is needed i might be able to switch. For printing i can use whatever software that is needed. At the moment im using gsprint http://www.ccp14.ac.uk/ccp/web-mirrors/ghostscript/gsview/gsprint.htm

Comment: a commercial solution that does this is Print&Share: https://www.printandshare.info